# Concatenate strings in a column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I am trying to transform the table below:

```
id  another_id_1 another_id_2  remarks
1   34.         151.         good
2.  34.         151.         okay
3.  34.         152.         bad
4.  34.         153.         very good
5.  34          153          okay
6.  34          154          good
7.  34          155          bad
```

Into

```
another_id_1 another_id_2 remarks
34.          151.         good, okay
34.          152.         bad
34.          153          very good, okay
34.          154          good
34           155          bad
```

the table below using postgresql statement:

Is there a way this can be achieved, Nothing I have tried  seemed to work

Comment: Please explain the logic, it is not clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited the question so the tables are well formatted. is this better?

Comment: Where does the `bad` in `good, okay, bad` in the first row come from? I can't see any row with (34, 151)  that contains `bad` as the remarks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am so sorry about that, I just edited the question again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although not consistent with your data, I think you want aggregation:

```
select another_id_1, another_id_2, 
       string_agg(remarks, ', ' order by id) as remarks
from t
group by another_id_1, another_id_2;
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response, I just tried this and It doesn't seem to be grouping them as expected. I also edited my question so the tables are well formatted. Can you please take a look again if you have some time? Thank you

Comment: this is the answer and it worked perfectly. I am buying your book right away.I want to know sql like you